# Upgrading to docker 1.9 on Centos 7.1

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, docker-registry

I am trying to upgrade to docker 1.9 from docker 1.8 version

I have used the following command to upgrade docker:

> sudo wget https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest -O
>   /usr/bin/docker

Howerver, after successful upgrade I am not able to restart the docker service.
The following command is failing

> sudo systemctl start docker

Please help

Comment: Please copy the error message as well

Comment: Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-12-13 19:53:16 GMT; 16s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 25552 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $ADD_REGISTRY $BLOCK_REGISTRY $INSECURE_REGISTRY (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 25552 (code=exited, status=2)

Comment: I am getting the above error

Comment: Is there any related message in syslog?

Comment: systemd: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
systemd: Starting Docker Storage Setup...
docker-storage-setup: Rounding up size to full physical extent 104.00 MiB
docker-storage-setup: Volume group "centos" has insufficient free space (16 extents): 26 required.
systemd: docker-storage-setup.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=5/NOTINSSTALLED

Comment: systemd: Failed to start Docker Storage Setup.
systemd: Unit docker-storage-setup.service entered failed state.
systemd: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
docker: flag provided but not defined: --add-registry
docker: See '/usr/bin/docker daemon --help'.
systemd: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
systemd: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
systemd: Unit docker.service entered failed state.

Comment: Above is output of /var/log/messages

Comment: Please run this script: https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh

Comment: Also try to stop firewalld and then start docker daemon

Answer (score 0):

It seems your disk is full. Check the disks `df -h`. And prepare enough disk space for your apps

Comment: Please let me know for which directory should i increase the disk space??

Comment: Could you please paste result of `du`. It should be part of vg--centos I guess

Comment: 0 ./.X11-unix  
0 ./.ICE-unix  
0 ./.XIM-unix  
0 ./.font-unix  
0 ./.Test-unix  
0 ./.esd-1000
4 ./vagrant-chef/e827c31a4deeee78ac1a08cee48190d2/cookbooks
4 ./vagrant-chef/e827c31a4deeee78ac1a08cee48190d2
4 ./vagrant-chef
0 ./.esd-1001
12 .

Comment: Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G  8.5G   42G  17% /
devtmpfs                 911M     0  911M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    921M  160K  921M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    921M  8.7M  912M   1% /run
tmpfs                    921M     0  921M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-home   46G   39M   46G   1% /home
/dev/sda1                497M  149M  349M  30% /boot
none                     239G  168G   71G  71% /vagrant
none                     239G  168G   71G  71% /tmp/vagrant-chef/e827c31a4deeee78ac1a08cee48190d2/cookbooks

Comment: I don't see any filesystem which is 100% full

Comment: the home directory is used only 1%. 99% is free

Comment: Hi Ali, I see you have deleted your previous comment. Please let me know if you are still willing to help me out.

Comment: @meallhour, yes I just find out that could be not from your disk space, instead try another path, adding some comment to question.